# Algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I got this problem "Implement this method to return the sum of the two largest numbers in a given array."

I resolved it in this way:

```
 public static int sumOfTwoLargestElements(int[] a) {

     int firstLargest = largest(a, 0, a.length-1);

     int firstLarge =  a[firstLargest];
     a[firstLargest] = -1;

     int secondLargest = largest(a, 0, a.length-1);

     return firstLarge + a[secondLargest];
}

private static int largest(int s[], int start , int end){

    if (end - start == 0){

        return end;
    }


   int a = largest(s, start, start + (end-start)/2) ;
   int b = largest(s, start + (end-start)/2+1 , end);
    if(s[a] > s[b]) {

       return a;
    }else {

      return b;
    }

}
```

Explanation: I implemented a method 'largeset'. This method is responsible to get the largest number in a given array.

I call the method tow times in the same array. The first call will get the first largest number.I put it aside into variable and i replace it by '-1' number into the array. Then, i call the largest medhod second time.

Some one can tell me what is the complexity of this algo? please

Comment: You can find both numbers in the first pass and spare the second pass. It won't change the complexity but it'll run faster. :-)

Comment: +1 for the above comment. Also if it is just a list of numbers, then there are various other ways of solving the same... if you use an mechanism like count sort etc with negligible extra space and O(n) time complexity...

Comment: The real measure of complexity is that of future readers of this code, the time they spend figuring out how this works, when a much simpler algorithm will do the job. There is no clear benefit to recursion, or why two passes through the set are needed. And the algorithm is fundamentally broken (returns an incorrect result) when the two largest integers in the array are both less than -1. Accckkk!

Answer (score 11):

The time complexity of the algorithm is `O(n)`.

Each recursive call's complexity is actually:

```
f(n) = 2*f(n/2) + CONST
```

It is easy to see (by induction<sup>1</sup>) that `f(n) <= CONST'*n` - and thus it is `O(n)`.

The space complexity is `O(logN)` - because this is the maximal depth of the recursion - so you allocate `O(logN)` memory on the call stack.

---

(1)
If you use `f(n) = 2*n*CONST - CONST` you get:

```
f(n) = 2*f(n/2) + CONST = (h.i.) 2*(2*CONST*n/2 - CONST) + CONST =
=  2*n*CONST - 2CONST + CONST = 2*n*CONST - CONST
```

(Checking the base is is left as exercise for the reader)

Comment: So, f(0) has negative complexity? I rather think the complexity is O(2^n * log n).

Comment: @undur_gongor The formula does not apply for the base or lower values, obviously (this is the point of induction, we prove from some point and up, all bets are off below it). The base should be for `f(1)`, and as mentioned left as an exercise.

Comment: @undur_gongor: And, to be exact - since we used only equality in the proof, we actually showed that the `f(n)` is in `Theta(n)` - so `O(n)` is a tight asymptotic bound.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity of the algorithm would be measured as `O(n)`.

But the real answer is that your algorithm is WAY more complex, and more expensive in terms of machine resources than it needs to be. And it's WAY more expensive in terms of someone reading your code and figuring out what it's doing.

The complexity of your algorithm should really be on the order of:

```
public static int sumOfTwoLargestElements(int[] a) {

    //TODO handle case when argument is null,
    //TODO handle case when array has less than two non-null elements, etc.

    int firstLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int v : a) {
        if ( v > firstLargest ) {
            secondLargest = firstLargest;
            firstLargest = v;
        } else if ( v > secondLargest ) secondLargest = v;
    }
    //TODO handle case when sum exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    return firstLargest + secondLargest;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need `if ( v > firstLargest )  { secondLargest = firstLargest; firstLargest = v };`

Answer (score 0):

The reccurence for 'Largest' method is:

```
        _
f(n) = !
       !  1        n = 1
       !  2f(n/2)  n >=2 
       !_

If we experiment some few cases, we notice that 

f(n) = 2^log(n)   When n is power of 2       Rq:Log base 2

Proof:

By induction,

f(1) = 2^log(1) = 2^log(2^0) = 1

We suppose that f(n) = 2^log(n)=n

We show f(2n) = 2^log(2n)= 2n^log(2)=2n

f(2n) = 2*f(2n/2) = 2*f(n)
                  = 2*2^log(n)
                  = 2^log(n) + 1
                  = 2^log(n) + log(2^0)
                  = 2^log(2n)
                  = 2n^log(2)  by log properties
                  = 2n
Then f(n) = 2^log(n)=n  When n is power of2-smooth function f(2n) < c f(n). it follows smooth function properties that **f(n) = theta of n**
```